# MTK Logger, MTK Android Suite Daemon, and omacp

Tags: applications, system-apps

I've got an Acer E380 running Android 4.2. I suddenly seem to have a load of "apps" in the *Settings > Apps > All* list, such as:

1. MTK logger
2. MTK android suite Daemon
3. omacp, and others

These all have worryingly high amounts of permissions - all are allowed to send texts, call numbers, access, modify and create contacts, accounts, etc. I have no recollection of installing these, and it looks to me to be some form of virus (and a little research online seems to back this up).

I've run Kaspersky and AVG virus scans, yet they say my device is clean - so I'm now at all as to what to do? Is this a virus and if so, how do I remove it, as there seems to be no APK files that has caused it.

PS. I'm not afraid of a factory reset either!

Comment: Seems like system apps. Searching for "MTK Android Suite Daemon" brings to [this app info](http://getandroidapp.org/applications/tools/9052-mtk-android-suite-daemon-1-1.html), and searching the package brings a (branch?) [source code of it](https://github.com/kupyxa4444/baoxue_mytqt-yywi/tree/master/mediatek/source/packages/MTKAndroidSuiteDaemon/src/com/mediatek/apst/target). I won't disable/remove them without more info, but if you're okay with factory reset, try to disable them.

Comment: First off, your research is a little incomplete – as there doesn't exist any ***virus*** for Android. Second, the "MTK" prefix seems to stand for "MediaTeK" – and indeed, [your device](http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_e3-6116.php) seems to be powered by a Mediatek MT6589 CPU. Which seems to suggest those are apps shipping with your device. Could you please go to *Settings › Apps*, select the "All" tab, and check for those apps? Open their entries, and see whether there's a button labeled "Disable" (i.e. app came pre-installed) or "Uninstall" (not pre-installed or system app).

Comment: Well I have a malware on my android which I introduced via rooting process with untrusted apk. Some of the files I suspect were introduced start with MTK (like MtkBt.apk, MTKAndroidSuiteDaemon.apk and MTKLogger.apk). Maybe someone is related to cracked [Mobileuncle MTK Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileuncle.toolbox) ?? I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

From the Looks of it, those apps seem to be part of the "bloatware" that comes with most phones out of the box.

In android, apps cannot be installed unless you choose for them to be installed. Even third party apps always show up with a "would you like to install this?" followed by the application and its permission. Then you have a final choice to install or not, based on the permissions it requires.